# What's the origin of "chock one up for something"?

Tags: phrase-origin

I know that it has the same meaning as "[chalk one up for](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/chalk-one-up-for.1040845/)", but I couldn't find out why it works with the word 'chock'. Is it something they used to do in the past, or is it simply a variation that came after "chalk one up for".

I came across it in an American English text.

Comment: It's just a typo

Comment: Sorry but seems very unlikely to me, If you google "chock one up for" with quotation marks, there are 296,000 results. Including some from books.google.com, and I found it in a book too.

Comment: It's still a typo.

Comment: What a widespread typo! Thank you both very much.

Comment: Or a widespread misunderstanding - an [_eggcorn_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn)

Comment: You're exactly right, Kate.

Comment: I'll note that several expressions along the lines of "rack one up" are reasonably legitimate and have roughly the same meaning as "chalk one up".  And, in particular, it's plausible to believe that some people confused "chock" and "rack".